# How to display all checkboxes values in a div using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have multiple checkboxes displayed from MySQL table. I'm trying to pass all checked values to `<div>` using `ajax`. Currently, my code only passes one checked value to `<div>`. I want to display all checked values in a `<div>`.

What I have thus far:

```
 <?php
$sql="SELECT  * FROM options WHERE cat_id='".$id."' AND opg_id='".$group."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $row['op_id']; ?>" onClick="showPrice(this.name)" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"/>

<!-- Display all prices from mysql table in checkbox. Pass `id` to ajax from name attribute. -->
<?php
} ?>
```

**ajax**

```
<script>
function showPrice(name) {
 $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_price.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {option : name},
        success: function(data) {
           document.getElementById('c').innerHTML =data;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**ajax_price.php**

```
<?php
include ("../supplier/DB/db.php");
$id = $_REQUEST['option'];

 <?php
$sql="SELECT  * FROM options WHERE op_id='".$id."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 ?> 
<div class="oder">
         <div class="odercol2"><?php echo $row['opt']; ?></div>
         <div class="odercol3"><?php echo $row['price']; ?></div>

    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

This is the display with only one checked value in the `<div>`. I want to display all the checked values in my `<div>`.

**checkboxes**

[image: checkboxes]

Results display in this div (div id is "c")

[image: Results display in this div]

Comment: So are you saying you have 3 checkboxes, you check one of the three, it shows you that one being checked but doesn't show you the other two, but you want it to show you the other unchecked boxes as well?

Comment: @Rasclatt yes.when is click on one checkbox it's display name and price in <div>.i want display all checked values in <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your AJAX function to concat the innerHTML of DIV, like this:

```
<script>
function showPrice(name) {
 $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_price.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {option : name},
        success: function(data) {
           document.getElementById('c').innerHTML += data;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Notice this line `document.getElementById('c').innerHTML += data;`
Hope it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a class value in the checkbox

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT  * FROM options WHERE cat_id='".$id."' AND opg_id='".$group."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

<input type="checkbox" class="sundarCheckBox" name="<?php echo $row['op_id']; ?>" onClick="showPrice(this.name)" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"/>

<!-- Display all prices from mysql table in checkbox. Pass `id` to ajax from name attribute. -->
<?php
} ?>
```

Loop using the class name input elements

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    function showPrice(value){

        $.each($('.sundarCheckBox'), function(index, element){

            if($(element).is(':checked')){

                alert($(element).prop('value'));
            }           
        });     
    }   
});
</script>
```

Comment: @tje not tested yet. please check and revert back. AJAX function is not included in showPrice(value) function please include it yourself.